# Why can't init-capturing mutable lambdas have mutable data members?

Tags: c++, lambda, language-lawyer, mutable, c++14

This question is related to [this previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21724760/819272) where it was noticed that init-capturing `mutable` lambdas are incompatible with Boost's range and iterator `transform` for some rather obscure and deeply nested `typedef` failures that may or may not be easy to resolve through hacking the Boost.Range sources.

The accepted answer suggested storing the lambda in a `std::function` object. To avoid potential `virtual` function call overhead, I wrote two function objects that could serve as potential work-arounds. They are called `MutableLambda1` and `MutableLambda2` in the code below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/range/adaptors.hpp>
#include <boost/range/algorithm.hpp>

// this version is conforming to the Standard
// but is not compatible with boost::transformed
struct MutableLambda1
{
    int delta;     
    template<class T> auto operator()(T elem) { return elem * delta++; }
};

// Instead, this version works with boost::transformed
// but is not conforming to the Standard
struct MutableLambda2
{
    mutable int delta;
    template<class T> auto operator()(T elem) const { return elem * delta++; }
};

// simple example of an algorithm that takes a range and laziy transformes that
// using a function object that stores and modifies internal state
template<class R, class F>
auto scale(R r, F f) 
{
    return r | boost::adaptors::transformed(f);
}

int main()
{
    // real capturing mutable lambda, will not work with boost::transformed
    auto lam = [delta = 1](auto elem) mutable { return elem * delta++; };        
    auto rng = std::vector<int>{ 1, 2, 3, 4 };

    //boost::copy(scale(rng, lam), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ","));                 /* ERROR */
    //boost::copy(scale(rng, MutableLambda1{1}), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ","));   /* ERROR */
    boost::copy(scale(rng, MutableLambda2{1}), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ","));     /* OK!   */
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a56fcb849a9b1e90) that won't compile the lines with `lam` and `MutableLambda1`, and correctly prints `1, 4, 9, 16` for the line with `MutableLambda2`.

However, the [**draft Standard**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf) mentions

**5.1.2 Lambda expressions [expr.prim.lambda]**

> 5 [...] This function call operator or operator template is declared const
>   (9.3.1) if and only if the lambda-expression’s
>   parameter-declaration-clause is not followed by `mutable`. [...]
>
> 11 For every init-capture a non-static data member named by the
>   identiﬁer of the init-capture is declared in the closure type. This
>   member is not a bit-ﬁeld and not `mutable`. [...]

This means that `MutableLambda2` is not a conforming handwritten replacement for an init-capturing `mutable` lambda expression.

### Questions

- why is the implementation of init-capturing `mutable` lambdas the way it is (i.e. non-const function call operator)?
- why is the seemingly equivalent alternative of `mutable` data members with a `const` function call operator forbidden?
- (**bonus**) why does the Boost range and iterator `transform` rely on the fact that a function objects `operator()` is `const`?

Comment: Sorry, I'm being really thick, but could you make a very short, boostless example of what you'd like to be able to do but can't?

Comment: @KerrekSB This question is really tied to Boost.Range, I'm afraid. I want to lazily transform a range of numbers using an algorithm that requires storing and modifying some internal state in the function object. Init-capturing mutable lambdas seem like the way to go, but give the proverbial template novel. `MutableLambda2` *does work* but does not have the same implementation as the Standard prescribes for lambdas. I wonder why that is the case, and if my workaround has any hidden pitfalls.

Comment: You're saying `MutableLambda2` is not conforming to the Standard. In which sense? As an implementation of lambda-expressions? -- mutable lambdas with non-const function call operators require non-const objects to be called on; OTOH const function call operators + `mutable` data members do not. Is that the difference you're looking for?

Comment: @dyp yes, suppose a compiler would emit `MutableLambda2` instead of `MutableLambda1` (as is required now), how would it break user code? As you point out, you could call the former on const objects, but why would that be bad? (since it is only modifying internal state, not the arguments being passed to `operator()`).

Comment: @TemplateRex Maybe you can expect some degree of "pureness" when you have a const ref to a function object. E.g. if the algorithm requires a pure function, because it may call it several times and get the same result. Also, you might want to keep two copies `a` and `b` consistent. When the function call operator is const, you might reasonably assume that using the function `a` and using the function `b` is interchangeable.

Comment: @dyp ah good point about pureness, I should have thought of that. If you can write it up, I'll accept that as an answer and keep `MutableLambda2` as a well-commented work-around for my problem until Boost catches up with init-capturing lambdas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template<class L>
struct force_const_call_t {
  mutable L f;
  template<class...Args>
  auto operator()(Args&&...args) const
  { return f(std::forward<Args>(args)...); }
};
template<class L>
force_const_call_t<L> force_const_call(L&&f){
  return {std::forward<L>(f)};
}
```

the above should let you take a lambda, wrap it in `force_const_call(` ... `)`, and call your `boost` algorithm, without a custom `mutable` callable object (or more precisely, the above turns lambdas into custom `mutable` callables).

Comment: Ha! I had been playing with wrapping mutable lambdas inside other lambdas, but this is pure genius for its simplicity.

Comment: Just a comment: it works and even works efficiently (all wrapping is optimized away in my application), but the price for faking a const signature of a mutable stateful function object (both by your solution and my handwritten one) is that the algorithm cannot assume anything stronger than input iterators / single pass ranges. Otherwise the order-dependence induced by the mutable state will trip you up. Caveat emptor!

Comment: @TemplateRex even worse, the algorithm could copy the state and evaluate different parts of the list with different copies of the state.  This kind of "bypass" of the requirements of the algorithm requires that you know that the algorithm was written wrong (it shouldn't be forcing `const` calls), and yet you are not allowed to rewrite it.  You **can** go one step further and write a wrapper that stores the lambda in a `std::shared_ptr<L>`, which means that copies of the now shared-function object use the same shared state, which may be wise.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, a mutable lambda requires a non-const function call operator in order to let const references to function objects represent pure functions.

It turns out that the culprit for my application is Boost.Iterator underyling the Boost.Range implementation of `boost::adaptors::transformed`. After some digging in the Boost.Iterator documentation's [requirements for `transform_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/iterator/doc/transform_iterator.html#transform-iterator-requirements), it turns out that (bold emphasis mine)

> The type `UnaryFunction` must be Assignable, Copy Constructible, and the
>   expression `f(*i)` must be valid where **`f` is a const object** of type
>   `UnaryFunction`, `i` is an object of type Iterator, and where the type of
>   `f(*i)` must be `result_of<const
>   UnaryFunction(iterator_traits<Iterator>::reference)>::type`.

Stateful non-pure function objects can therefore not be written using lambdas but instead have to written using a `const` function call `operator()` and with `mutable` data members representing the state. This was also remarked in [this related Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12820104/use-boosttransform-iterator-with-a-non-const-functor).

**Note**: there is an [open bug report](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/4969) for this.